# Appropriate Status Code for Incorrect Requested Type

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, polymorphism, swagger, http-status-codes

If you have a REST API that can be used to access a unique owner and then one registered pet - what kind of status code would be most appropriate to signify that a Pet exists, but is not found at the current URL?

`/Owner/{id}` -- Get operation to access Owner Object (Which includes a reference to any complicated nested objects.

`/Owner/{id}/Dog` -- Get Operation to access a Dog.

`/Owner/{id}/Cat` -- Get Operation to access a Cat.

If the requested Owner has a Dog, what kind of response should `/Owner/{id}/Cat` return?

It feels like this should return some kind of reference that says there is a Pet, which points the caller to `/Owner/{id}/Dog`.

I don't think a 404 would be correct because it doesn't make the API very discover-able (likewise with 5xx status codes), though no 2xx status codes seem to give me what I want either, 3xx status codes seem to infer infrastructure changes rather than the resource is found at a different location.

[edit: Shortly after posting this question I discovered the `303 - See Other` Status code. Would this be the better way to go?]

What do you think is the best Status Code to return in this instance?

---

For some background

1. This is a generic example of what it is I want to achieve - in practice I am actually storing/accessing authentication information (I.e. OAuth2, PAT etc) which is too different to condense onto a flat object without having lots of fields that won't be relevant to other types.
2. Code Generation is really important - This API is being made available via an internal micro service which can only be accessed via a GraphQL endpoint (which acts as an API Gateway). This makes it relatively undesirable to have a single endpoint that returns multiple different types (I.e. `owner/{id}/pet` which would return either a Dog, Cat, or Fish based on the type you happened to own).

   - That being said, if offering multiple different endpoints instead of one is not the way you would go about doing this I am open to other options (obviously taking into consideration point 1 on this list).
3. Preferably, I would like this to be Swagger Compliant if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting this question I discovered the `303 - See Other` Status Code, which appears to be appropriate in this instance.

P.S. I've updated the question with this information, and will leave the question open because I'm still interested to find out if someone else things there is a more appropriate solution and/or best practice.